# How to store rest response data into Salesforce custom object as records

Tags: json, rest, apexrest

I have created REST service which is fetching prospect data from pardot and now I want to store it into Salesforce's custom object. I have some fields inthis object which I need to map from the response returned.

Response:

```
"result":{
 "prospect":[   {"id":1704281,"campaign_id":969,"user_id":null,"salutation":"Ms","first_name":"t
 est","last_name":"Akin"}]}
```

In the REST class I am de-serializing the data as below but getting "Attempt to de-refrence null"

```
 if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
 Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
 List<Object> prospects = (List<Object>) results.get('prospect');
  for (Object prospectob: prospects) {  // Getting Error - Attempt to de-ref null
     System.debug('*******'+prospectob);
   }
}
```

I found that the below line is the cuprit, it is not fetching the data from the response returned by the service.

```
 List<Object> prospects = (List<Object>) results.get('prospect');
```

Can somebody please point out what's wrong in here.

Answer (score 1):

The top-level object is `result`:

```
Map<String, Object> result = 
  (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody()).get('result');
Object[] prospects = (Object[])result.get('prospect');
```

It's usually worth trying [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) so you can get the correct object names.